# ASP.NET Web API Architecture Suggestion/Feedback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Currently I am faced with the requirement building an web service that will let a java client retrieve and trigger actions on our data through httprequest. We are a .Net shop it appears the latest solution for this is Microsoft's MVC4 Web API. I am used to your standard tiered architecture I have pulled data from API's but this will be my first web service supplying data.

From my studies I have seen suggestions as follows:

- Separating the logic and data access into a separate project type class library.
- Using your Controls to access data and perform logic.
- Using your Model to access data and perform logic.

I am looking for someone who has experience with MVC4 Web API who can shed some light on good practices for building a web service in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think this question is a bit vague. Could you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Something like: "What should the design of my Web Service be? Here is what I am thinking"? Perhaps... This question seems too open ended.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the welcome. I am afraid the vagueness of my question matches my knowledge on the MVC 4 product. I was thinking two options. The first option would be to separating my logic and data access into separate class library projects with the possibility of reusing code and better organization.  Alternatively another option would be to just use the MVC shell and use the model for my business logic and data access which I felt could get really crowded fast as this project get bigger down the road.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API != ASP.NET MVC http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/newsflash-asp-net-web-api-does-not-sit-on-top-of-asp-net-mvc-in-fact-it-does-not-sit-on-top-of-anything Just FYI :)

Comment: Wow, I meant to type MVC 4 Web Api late night when I sent that in. :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, do put your ASP.NET Web API logic into a separate project. This will give you flexibility over hosting layer (as ASP.NET Web API is hosting agnostic) and it just makes the whole project clean. Let's say your project's name is MyProject. You can name the API project as `MyProject.API` and you can install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` NuGet package into this project.

I also suggest you to separate your domain layer as well (POCO entities, repositories, your service layer pieces, etc.). Let's call this `MyProject.Domain`. Then, you would reference this `MyProject.Domain` project from the `MyProject.API`project.

I wouldn't recommend you to dump all your POCO entities into your API. So, I would definately work with Data Transfer Objects (Dto). You can use a 3rd party tool like autoMapper to map your entity classes to your Dtos. However, do put your Dtos, Request Commands, Request Models into a separate project. You would reference `MyProject.API.Model` project from `MyProject.API` project. Why do we create a separate project for this? Because, later if you decide to build a .NET client wrapper for your HTTP API, you can easily reference this project to use those with your .NET client as well. Let's call this project `MyProject.API.Model`.

Lastly, we need a hosting layer for our API. Asumming that you would like to host this project under ASP.NET, you can create a new project through the Empty Web Application template and let's call this project `MyProject.API.WebHost`. Then, you can  install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` package into this project.  From this project, you would reference `MyProject.API`, `MyProject.API.Model` and `MyProject.Domain` projects. This project is the one that you should deploy to your server.

If you would like to create a .NET wrapper for your HTTP API, you can create another project called `MyProject.API.Client` and install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package into this one. You would also reference the `MyProject.API.Model` project from this one so that you can deserialize into and serialize from strongly-typed objects.

Here is the screenshot of the solution explorer for the project I have been working with:

[image]

Hope this gives you a bit of an idea.

Comment: It does thank you for the feedback. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: :-\  This is really starting to sound like https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Comment: @DanEsparza let me know if any one of those layers don't make sense to you and I'll tell you why it's there.

Comment: I known its bit old post but I am working on best practices and I was searching the web I end up here. So my question is can you differentiate between API vs API client vs API client web? I am not sure.