# Recommended approach to hosting a two-tier web application in Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm fooling around with a WebAPI application I've developed in two solutions: one solution is the WebAPI / serverside solution with db access using SQL server, the other is a durandalJS client application.  I have the WebAPI bits hosted in an Azure Website right now, but I'm not sure where to put the client solution.

Should I throw it in its own website and just have it make requests within azure across to the other website?  I want to avoid putting them in the same solution because I would eventually like to practice load balancing the front-ends when I have more dough to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea of cloud like Azure is pay as you go. If you do not have the volume currently to load-balance, why create two websites and pay for them both regardless of the usage? You can have just one web site and host both the web application and web API. In the future, if you want to separate out API piece and load balance web app, you can do that when you have the volume. For this approach to work, structure the solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285693). The Web API piece will be just an assembly which you can reference in the Web application itself and host it in the same web site as the web application. In future, if you want to separate out, create a new empty ASP.NET Web application and host the Web API referencing your Web API core assembly.

Comment: Thank you Badri.  Right now I'm having all AJAX calls to WebAPI go to the xyz.azurewebsites.net - this is working.  If I push everything into the same solution, where should I point the requests?

Comment: Say, xyz.azurewebsites.net is the URL for web API and abc.azurewebsites.net is the URL for your web app. Since your web API will be also be part of the same application as the client app, your new API URL will also be abc.azurewebsites.net. You will be calling the API using a URI like this, for example, abc.azurewebsites.net/api/values. Or you can simply use api/values. This is exactly same as having your API controller and MVC controller in the same project with JavaScript from your view calling the API.

Comment: A couple of things. [1] When you have both web app and the web api in the same site, there is no need to implement any thing like CORS to handle same origin restrictions. But when you move the api to a different site, you will need to. [2] The idea of having multiple instances for the web app alone will work only if you have significant portion of requests that can be served by the web app itself, may be like static content and stuff. If every hit in your app gets translated to a hit in your API, you would need to scale out your API as well by creating more instances.

Comment: The more the better coming from someone of your stature :).  Thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm going to continue working on bringing the client into the webApi solution as you've advised.

Comment: Just caught your update.  I suppose I'll try to leave the CORS work intact as I've spent the past week on it, so hopefully I can avoid rework if/when splitting the tiers is necessary.